# Environment variable not being picked up by Node/Express/Nuxt app

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, sendgrid, nuxt.js

I am trying to setup SendGrid with my Vue/Nuxt app, however I can only get it to to work by hardcoding the API key. When I try to use the preferred environment variable method, I get an **unauthorized error**. This is because the app is not picking up the variable, instead it returns *Undefined*.

How do I make the app get the variable?

My API KEY is kept in a filed called **sendgrid.env** in the project root.

I then have a Node/Express app running within my Nuxt project with the following code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('API root')
})

app.get('/sendmail', (req, res, next) => {

// using Twilio SendGrid's v3 Node.js Library
// https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

const msg = {
    to: 'somebody@something.net',
    from: 'no-reply@somewhereelse.com',
    subject: 'Test SendGrid',
    text: 'This is a test of the SendGrid app on Node',
    html: '<strong>This is a test of the SendGrid app on Node</strong>',
};

sgMail.send(msg);

res.send('SendMail API');

})

// export the server middleware
module.exports = {
  path: '/api',
  handler: app
}
```

I have tested the code using Curl and also by hardcoding the API Key, so the key is correct, it's just the environment variable that's not being picked up.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have `"dotenv": "^6.2.0"` in the dependencies section of your `package.json` file?

And `require('dotenv').config();` in your main JS file?

Those lines are required to get it work.

Comment: Yes, I do - I have resolved the issue though, and am just typing up an answer. Will post it shortly.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have solved the issue.

It seems that using **@nuxt/dotenv** causes issues with reading from environment variables.

I removed **@nuxt/dotenv** and just installed **dotenv via npm**, then placed the API key in the .env file and it was picked up.

Leaving here in case it helps anyone else having a similar issue.